# Would you please help me to understand the difference between “just then” and “that’s when”?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Consider the following examples:

1. Just then he saw the fish.
2. That’s when he saw the fish.

Is there any difference in meaning between these examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joe Z. says, these have distinct syntactic structures.

They can also have distinct meanings. Both refer to the time when the fish was seen, and both *That's when* and *just then* may be used to refer to a specific moment in time:

> <sup>ok</sup>Joe turned. That’s when he saw the fish.
>   <sup>ok</sup>Joe turned. Just then he saw the fish.

But *that's when* can also refer to a broad timespan, while *just then* cannot, because it means “at that very moment”:

> <sup>ok</sup>Joe spent 2010 in Colorado. That’s when he saw the fish.
>   <sup>∗</sup> Joe spent 2010 in Colorado. Just then he saw the fish.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  *marks a usage as unacceptable*
<sup>ok</sup> *marks a usage as acceptable*

Answer (score 2):

Well, speaking strictly from a grammatical point of view, "he saw the fish" is an independent clause in the first sentence and part of a subordinate clause in the second one:

> Just then, **he saw the fish**.
>
> That's **when he saw the fish**.

But from a narrative point of view, they serve roughly the same purpose. They both introduce an event that is key to the plot of the story, occurring at a very specific moment in time.